# Puppet 7.10 notify attribute in file resource type unable to find a running service

Tags: apache2, puppet

New to puppet and I am getting confused by two issues:

(1) Installing a package (`apache2`) not only installs the package but also starts the service. Is this happening due to perhaps scripts triggered by `apache2` during installation?

(2) `puppet resource service apache2` shows that `apache2` is running. But when I try to run `sudo puppet apply apache2-file.pp` I get the error as shown below:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ puppet resource service apache2
service { 'apache2':
  ensure   => 'running',
  enable   => 'true',
  provider => 'systemd',
}
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ cat apache2-file.pp 
file { '/etc/apache2/ports.conf':
    ensure => present,
    replace => true,
    source => '/home/ubuntu/ports.conf',
    notify => Service['apache2']
}
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo puppet apply apache2-file.pp 
Error: Could not find resource 'Service[apache2]' in parameter 'notify' (file: /home/ubuntu/apache2-file.pp, line: 5) on node ubuntu-xenial
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, basically the package, file, and service resources need to be a part of a single `sudo puppet apply` operation. I was installing package as part of one puppet apply, then updating file as part of another puppet apply, and running the service as part of third puppet apply.

Comment: This is correct.  Resources' `notify` metaparameters (and other relationship metaparameters) refer to Puppet resources in the same catalog, not directly to target-system physical resources.  It is an error for them to specify resources that are not present in the catalog.